# how to get the type of a pointer in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following:

```
type* ptr;
```

And I want to get `type` out of `ptr`. I tried using `declval`/`declval`/`decay` but can't get it to work (thats what happens when you dont have deep understanding of what you are doing).

So how can I get the type and create a variable of the same type - like `type some_var;`

Comment: Is `type` a template parameter?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall no - assume the pointer is some local variable in the same scope - and say it is ```int```

Comment: `std::pointer_traits<decltype(ptr)>::element_type`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) type trait:

```
using ptr_type = int*;
using type = std::remove_pointer<ptr_type>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<type, int>::value, "");
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `decltype` and `std::declval`:

```
using ptr_type = int*;
using type = decltype(*std::declval<ptr_type>());

static_assert(std::is_same<type, int>::value, "");
```

You might also need to use `std::remove_reference` if you're using a *dereferencing expression* directly inside `decltype`:

```
int* ptr = nullptr; 
std::remove_reference<decltype(*ptr)>::type var = 7;
```

Comment: This doesn't work: ```int* ptr = nullptr;
    std::remove_pointer<decltype(ptr)> var = 7;```

Comment: @onqtam: did you read the answer and the linked documentation? You need to use `::type`.

Comment: @onqtam: again, it's in the linked `cppreference` page, under the "Possible implementation" section :)